# date in woocommerce REST API

Tags: javascript, php, woocommerce

Hi i would like create a filter in dashboard that get today orders and filter by date

```
$results  = $woocommerce->get('orders');

<div id="blog-overview-date-range" class="input-daterange input-group input-group-sm my-auto ml-auto mr-auto ml-sm-auto mr-sm-0" style="max-width: 350px;">
                          <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="start" placeholder="Start Date" id="blog-overview-date-range-1">
                          <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="end" placeholder="End Date" id="blog-overview-date-range-2">
                          <span class="input-group-append">
                            <span class="input-group-text">
                              <i class="material-icons"></i>
                            </span>
                          </span>
                        </div>
```

thank you

Comment: What have you tried? This is not a code-writing service, but lots of folks are happy to help improve/fix/tweak code that you have written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$from = 2018-08-01;
$to   = 2018-08-09; 
$parameters = array(
             'after'  =>$from,
             'before' => $to
              );
$woocommerce->get('orders', $parameters);
```

To get orders list between specific dates you can use after and before parameters in ISO8601 compliant date as stated in their documentation. 
read [documentation](http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?php#list-all-orders) for more info.